# Executing HTTP requests using Asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-asyncio

**The following function needs to send request asynchronously:**

*No. of rows in devices.csv = 1 million*

*Required: send a POST request for all 1 million rows per day for 3 days*

```
def check_in():
    logging.info('Starting')
    day = 0
    while day < 3:
        logging.info('Check-in Day = ' + str(day))
        with open('devices.csv', newline='') as csvfile: 
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
                device_sn = row['serial_number']
                payload = {
                    "product": "##",
                    "board": "###",
                    "hardware_id": "0000",
                    "usage_id": "000",
                    "mac_address": row['mac_address'],
                    "serial_number": row['serial_number']
                }
                logging.info(
                    'Check-in device: ' + device_sn)
                checkin_post(payload, device_sn)
            day += 1
```

```
def checkin_post(payload, device_sn):
    payload = payload
    serial_number = device_sn

    print('\n' + 72 * '=' + '\nPOST /device/' +
          serial_number + '/check-in')

    resp = requests.post(base_url + '/device/' +
                         serial_number + '/check-in', auth=auth, json=payload)

    print(resp.status_code)
```

**The code might change to probably something like:**

```
async def checkin_post(payload, device_sn):

    payload = payload
    serial_number = device_sn

    print('\n' + 72 * '=' + '\nPOST /device/' +
          serial_number + '/check-in')

    resp = requests.post(base_url + '/device/' +
                         serial_number + '/check-in', auth=auth, json=payload)
    return resp.status_code


async def main(payload, device_sn):
    checkin_post(payload, device_sn)
```

Also, since there is no `await`, it isn't truly asynchronous.

Comment: as it stands this question is too broad. have you tried converting it from requests to asyncio yourself?

Comment: @wpercy I have posted what I tried, I am sure Its incorrect.

Comment: either you execute the call to requests within a thread pool or you look at aiohttp

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for replying late if you already got it fixed by now.
But you need to return ensure_future object.
Can you try following code:

```
async def check_in():
    logging.info('Starting')
    count = 0
    futures = []
    while count < 3:
        logging.info('Check-in Day = ' + str(count))
        with open('devices.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
                device_sn = row['serial_number']
                payload = {
                    "product": "##",
                    "board": "###",
                    "hardware_id": "0000",
                    "usage_id": "000",
                    "mac_address": row['mac_address'],
                    "serial_number": row['serial_number']
                }
                logging.info(
                    'Check-in device: ' + device_sn)
                async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
                    async with session.post(base_url + '/device/' + device_sn + '/check-in', auth=auth, json=payload) as resp:
                        futures.append(asyncio.ensure_future(await resp.status))
            count += 1
    return await asyncio.gather(*futures)

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    futures = asyncio.ensure_future(check_in())
    responses = loop.run_until_complete(futures)
```

Comment: I have updated my question, *payload* and *serial_number* are passed from another function.

Comment: have you tried removing print(resp.status) statement? probably you can print status before waiting for the response.

Comment: Please look at my trials in the answers below. this doesn't work too.

Comment: Please edit your original question instead of posting new answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Comment: @jtbandes thanks for reviewing it. Edited my original answer.